# Unable to obtain lock in Adminserver.lok

Tags: weblogic

I have followed the below steps 
Navigate to tmp folder in your $DOMAIN_HOME directory. (for example: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain\servers\AdminServer\tmp)
Delete the lock file for the server instance, AdminServer.lok
Check if there are any java.exe processes are running, which should not be there. If there are any, they would have to be killed.
Restart your server

But still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I was also not able to publish my EAR to oracle weblogic server on localhost. I resolved this same issue by deleting **AdminServer.lok** file which located at

`your_directory/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/AdminServer.lok`

I restarted the server and able to deploy EAR to weblogic server.

Comment: This file `AdminServer.lok` does not even exist at that location.

Answer (score 0):

This could be either because the server is still running or it did not stop cleanly since the last run. If one knows the port at which it is running one can type the following command in the command prompt to identify the process id and kill it.

```
   netstat -ano | findstr <specify port number>
   taskkill /F /PID <process id from the above command>
```

Else, one may kill all running Java processes using the following command and be done with it.

```
    taskkill /F /im java.exe
```

Regards!